# Completely replace MySQL (or any SQL) DB with Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, google-api, google-sheets

**Let's say HYPOTHETICALLY that...**

I am building a webtool that pushes data onto a user-selected MySQL table in a user-selected MySQL database using user-selected MySQL username `[bogus_username]` with user-selected MySQL password `[bogus_password]`.

I would like to extend this **hypothetical** tool's capability to where it can push data onto any sort of database.

Technically, a Google Sheet is a "database."

So, how do I **hypothetically** build a script that logs onto a user's google drive and opens a google sheet up for data manipulation?

I am looking for a solution that either uses client-side JS, nodeJS, or PHP. Either language will do. **I am just trying to understand how to do this CONCEPTUALLY**, so what language you build the script in doesn't matter, as long as I can understand it.

<sup>all these "hypothetical"s mean I KNOW I DON'T HAVE CODE! I am not looking for code, but for code concept</sup>

Comment: at an abstract level, sheet's form feature adds a new row to a sheet upon filling a form, much like html forms tell php how to add a row to an sql db.

Answer (score 1):

Google sheets has a an api. There are many modules which use this api or provide wrappers for this api. Since you mention NodeJS you could hust do an npm search.

Somewhere in your code you will have a storeRecord function which could, depending on your configuration, store the data to mysql or google sheets, or whatever. You will need to implement some different code for database systems that do not use the same protocol. If the protocol is the same (e.g. ODBC is used by many databases) then you will just require different configuration settings.